# SQL query distinct with additional select

Tags: mysql, distinct

I need to perform a query in MySQL that returns distinct values for product_id but also I need to select and return 'id' field which is in that particular table.

This query will return distinct product_id's without id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM orders_cart
```

This query will use distinct on both fields which and I want to use it on product_id and see the id

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, product_id FROM orders_cart
```

It would be quite easy to do on pgsql but I have no idea how to do this on mysql.

Comment: What about this ? SELECT DISTINCT product_id,id  FROM orders_cart

Comment: @MoyedAnsari how different is that from OPs sql? I think column order doesn't matter in distinct

Comment: Well I actuallu used for pg sql django orm with .distinct("field_name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not well-defined: Consider this table

```
id   product_id
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     2
```

What should your query result be? If you mean

```
id        product_id
1 or 3     1
2 or 4     2
```

you are in the land of non-deterministic queries.

What you could do is

```
SELECT MIN(id), product_id FROM orders_cart GROUP BY product_id
```

which would deterministically produce

```
id   product_id
1     1
2     2
```

Comment: `SELECT id, product_id FROM orders_cart GROUP BY product_id` is non-deterministic: You will get one of the ids, but it is not strictly defined which. `SELECT MIN(id), product_id FROM orders_cart GROUP BY product_id` is deterministic, it will give you the smallest id.

Answer (score 0):

Thats my final code:
The most important bits for this issue were line 1,2 and 4 :)
GROUP BY did the trick :)

```
SELECT orders_cart.id, product_id, order_id 
FROM orders_cart 
LEFT JOIN orders_order ON orders_cart.order_id=orders_order.id
WHERE orders_order.status='Wysłano'
GROUP BY orders_cart.product_id
```